# Global Catch clause in java application

Tags: java, exception

I am having couple of method in `dao` file related to `DB operations` .like

```
public int addStudent(Student student) throws MyAppException, SQLException {
 // adding student in db
 }
```

And in my `controller` i am using like

```
 try{
  myObj.addStudent(student);
 }catch(Exception e){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage());
    alert.showAndWait();
 }
```

I am able to show the dialog mesages on `Error` but want to handle at one place instead of each and every `catch clause`   , something like

```
  public void myGlobalCatchhandler(Exception e){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage());
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

at one place insted of each catch clause of try block.

Comment: Looks like you are using spring? If yes, look up how to handle exceptions in spring..

Comment: There is nothing like a "global catch clause" in standard Java. You could write a static function to perform your action and call it in every `catch`; but that's about it.

Comment: Throw exceptions instead of catching it into sub methods and handle or catch them into root parent method...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of approaches that may help here.

- `@SneakyThrows` from [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) will allow to throw checked exceptions without `catch` block;
- If all the data access activities happen in a custom thread(s), you may handle all uncaught runtime exceptions in `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`;
- Aspects may help a lot, see [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-exception-translation);
- Most frameworks has their own exception handling mechanism, for example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) is Spring Framework tutorial;
- If all of previous cases make a lot of extra work for you case, I'd suggest to just extract all the exception handling logic into a separate method, and use it in `catch` block every time;
- If you really hate `try-catch`, you may introduce some wrapper method, like this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface DatabaseAction<T> {
    T execute() throws MyAppException, SQLException;
}

<T> T performDatabaseAction(DatabaseAction<T> action) {
    try {
        return action.execute();
    } catch (MyAppException | SQLException e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        alert.showAndWait();
        return null;
    }
}
```